# Undefined ofset

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

Facing error of undefined offset. If I remove `$ship = $ship->toArray();` then the data of a particular table becomes N/A. I Need to show the name under that particular table.

Controller

```
 ->addColumn('captain', function ($ship) {
                $ship = $ship->toArray();
                $user = User::pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
                if (!empty($ship['company_employee'])) {
                    $captain = $user[($ship['company_employee']['user_id'])];
                } else {
                    $captain = 'N/A';
                }
                return $captain;
            })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code may be its worked

```
->addColumn('captain', function ($ship) {
                $ship = $ship->toArray();
                $user = User::pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
                if (!empty($ship->company_employee)) {
                    $captain = $user[($ship->company_employee->user_id)];
                } else {
                    $captain = 'N/A';
                }
                return $captain;
            })
```

Comment: `->addColumn('captain', function ($ship) {
                $userId = CompanyEmployee::whereShipId($ship->id)->first();
                if (!is_null($userId)) {
                    $user = User::whereId($userId->user_id)->first();
                    $captain = !is_null($user) ? $user->name : 'N/A';
                }
                else
                    return 'N/A';
                return $captain;
            })`

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this:

```
->addColumn('captain', function ($ship) {
                if (!empty($ship->companyEmployee)) {
                    $user = User::pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
                    $captain = !empty($user[($ship->companyEmployee->user_id)])?$user[($ship->companyEmployee->user_id)]:'N/A';
                }
                else {
                    $captain = 'N/A';
                }
                return $captain;
            })
```